# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'. > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: react-native

I am facing this problem, I try Multiple solutions but no luck
My build.gradle file consist

```
 compileSdkVersion = 30
 targetSdkVersion = 30
```

I also add following lines in build.gradle

```
 configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
        }
    }
```

also, try these
https://exerror.com/solved-execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata/
also, install node_mudule much time
also reset cache and Gradle clean but found no luck
if anyone has any solution please update me

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced with this problem,When I changed position of **maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}** from below to up and add **maven { url "https://maven.google.com"}**
Then the problem disappear.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it does not work for me.
i just follow this
reactnative/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/react-native-reanimated-6*.aar.
Just go to the above path and copy the files and rename what is required, For example, if the problem is not finding 66.aar copy & paste the previous main aar file and hermen aar file in the path and rename it with 66 (from github)
it work for me

Comment: can you explain me why its not creating react-native-reanimated-66.aar

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the last package you added to your project `npm uninstall <package-name>`
and then run again.